# Making a custom Button using a UIView or overriding UIButton?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I need to generate a custom button through code, this is how i am currently doing it.

```
-(void) initialiseButtons 
{
    int ypos = playerImage.frame.origin.y + playerImage.frame.size.height + 8;
    for(int i=0; i<totalButtons; i++) 
    {       
        UIButton *newButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];    
        [newButton setFrame:CGRectMake(20, ypos, 220, 30)];
        newButton.tag = 10 + i;
        [newButton addTarget:self action:@selector(statTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.frontView addSubview:newButton];
        ypos += 30 + 7;
    }
}
```

This creates the blank buttons perfectly through code, gives them a tag and assigns an callback function on touchUpInside.

The custom button needs to be able to handle showing an image when pressed down.
It needs to be able to draw 2 pieces of Text. 1 aligned to the left hand side of the button and 1 aligned to the righthand side of the button.

My boss suggested instead of buttons I use a View. I dont understand how this will work. When i start thinking about it, i think it would require having a viewcontroller dedicated to the buttons. And some draw method? It sounds complicated and I am not grasping how it can be done.

Is there a simpler method by making a custom class overriding UIButton? I made a simple test class earlier but nothing was drawn in the buttons locations when I used them in place of the Normal UIButton class. I expected i would see the buttonUp.png drawn.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CardButton : UIButton {
}
@end


#import "CardButton.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@implementation CardButton
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame 
{
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) 
    {
        [self setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonUp.png"] forStates:UIControlStateNormal];
        self.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = YES;
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Anybody able to give me some pointers on this? I'm pretty blocked at the moment. Have been reading some various other threads related to buttons but nothing that made it clear in my head how to tackle the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not (I'd almost say you can't) subclass `UIButton`, as it turns out to be a class cluster, and it would be impractical (read: impossible) to derive from that.

So your two options are:

1) Use standard `UIButton` of custom type, add the elements you want to show (i.e. `UILabel`) and hook up actions for touch down and touch up and react accordingly (change the views, trigger actions etc.)

2) Use a custom `UIView`, implement `drawRect:` to draw how you like it or use custom views as subviews as in 1). Then use the `touchesBegan:`, `touchesEnded:` etc. messages to react accordingly (or `UIGestureRecognizer` if you can live with 3.2+ compatibility).

You might build a factory to build those buttons if they all are very similar, so that your code becomes clean and non-repetive.

**Edit as per iOS 6:**
Apple now mentions subclassing in the UIButton docs, so while still not very well defined, it seems quite safe now to do so.

Comment: CAnt figure out how to do this. Gonna leave it 24hours and see if it makes more sense when i come back to it. THanks for the help Eiko its appreciated :)

Comment: @Lechazar Todorov Just make a (static) class method *somewhere* that creates and configures the button. That way you can create as many buttons of this sort as you want, yet don't have to fiddle with the discouraged subclassing.

Comment: This is not true. You CAN most certainly subclass UIButton. I'm doing it right now. Apple has documentation that talks about doing it. I'm puzzled as to why you are saying it is not possible or impractical. There are a few classes that Apple says DO NOT SUBCLASS but UIButton is not one of them.

Comment: @FeloneousCat You can do *many* things in ObjC that you shouldn't. Technically it is possible - no doubt. And it works. But as UIButton has no designated initializer, and its type property cannot be set (it is *readonly*), there is no way to properly configure the subclass. The only documented way to instantiate a button is through its factory method (+buttonWithType:). So yes, it works. It works now. It will compile. Will it work tomorrow? Will it work on Wednesdays? We just cannot tell. That's why it is bad practice.

Comment: @Eiko In the UIButton documentation there is even text in +buttonWithType: that says "It you subclass UIButton...". This is NOT the same as saying "do not subclass". Apple even talks about subclassing UIButton here: [Defining Classes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/DefiningClasses/DefiningClasses.html) So, despite what you (and a few others think), UIButton can be subclassed. Apple even talks about subclassing it. How you get "it can't be subclassed" is beyond me.

Comment: @Eiko You will also find [-backgroundRectForBounds](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/backgroundRectForBounds:) this: "Subclasses that provide custom background adornments can override this method and return a modified bounds rectangle to prevent the button from drawing over any custom content."

Comment: @FeloneousCat Thank you for your comments. Indeed subclassing is mentioned now. Please note that this is new in iOS 6.0 - you can check the older docs: they do not mention any subclassing. Again - I never stated you *can't* subclass, but merely you shouldn't. If Apple now states that subclassing is OK, you're probably fine. Before that (and this question came up in 2010) it was code poker.

Comment: @Eiko Apple has never said that you shouldn't subclass UIButton. You said "shouldn't" but never offered an explanation why - just a "because". Um, sorry, but I've been writing ObjC since OS X Beta and the assumption has ALWAYS been "all objects can be subclassed except for those explicitly documented". I write to documentation, not to peoples fears and superstition. "probably fine"? - never was a problem to begin with.

Comment: @FeloneousCat If you feel happy with undefined behavior, that's just fine. Again - there's a vital property, the buttonType, that you can't configure (read loudly: it is **undefined**), but this property directly effects the object's behavior. Relying on what you observe in iOS w.x might easily break in iOs y.z. It often works, but there's no contract you rely on. What would you tell someone asking how the button behaved with an unset buttonType? It is or was a gamble. You won. Good for you.

Comment: @Eiko buttonType is not programmatically configurable - it IS configurable using **IB**. In ObjC, if you do not set a variable to a value it will be zero - **that is fundamental to the language.** It is not that we disagree, but you and many others are wrong. **Zero is not an undefined value**. It was never a gamble because I read the API documentation. You (and many others) jumped to a conclusion based on other programming languages - a false conclusion in ObjC. I won, but it was because I understood the nature of the language, not because of luck.

Comment: @FeloneousCat Zero is perfectly fine and defined. But you just don't know if it will be zero. It will be whatever the UIButton initializer choses it to set to. And this is the point that is not documented at all. I think it would be a bit too harsh to say that the init function (that you call) is a private (i.e. undocumented) method - with all the consequences regarding the AppStore policy - but it comes (or came, luckily) very close.

Comment: @Eiko So now we have it. NOTHING is undefined - probably zero, but not undefined (**read loudly**). By using IB, not only is it defined, but known as well. Which results in the following point: **it is perfectly safe, and has always been safe, to subclass UIButton**. It's also a good idea to use IB when doing so.

Comment: @FeloneousCat I give up. If IB (or some KVC tricks) fiddling is the only way to set a property, there is some serious design issue. Indeed, I wonder how setting a property for something that is a class cluster can be expected to work. There is no contract whatsoever telling you which functionality is your base class and which in the actual class you get using the factory method. But again, I give up.

Comment: By the way, just check Apple Dev Forums - it has been repeated over and over again that it is *not* recommended.

Comment: @Eiko Class clusters, according to Apple Documentation, can be [subclassed](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW34). NSArray, NSString and NSDictionary are class clusters. Not only that, but Apple **identifies** class clusters - they don't depend on hearsay. Assumption is NOT a valid design technique. BTW I looked on Apple Dev Forums and I see no such recommendation by anyone from Apple.

Comment: [Matt Neuburg](http://www.apeth.net/matt/cv/computercareer.html) writes professionally for iOS (as I do). He has talked about subclassing UIButton [here](http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2010/Jun/msg00244.html) - no comments about how it is impossible. How about his book? "iOS 5" from O'Reilly - Page 730 [here](http://tinyurl.com/a6c9pps) talks about **subclassing UIButton**.

Answer (score 6):

Personally, I would subclass UIButton. Despite all the talk that you can't subclass UIButton, Apple even talks about subclassing UIButton in the UIButton documentation.

In the subclass I would create a UIView with the two labels (or images or whatever) and add them as subviews to the button (be sure to set interactive for the text and view as FALSE).

What is awesome about this is that it leverages the UIButton code and keeps you from reinventing the wheel.

Comment: BTW, the documentation for UIButton even talks about subclassing it. It is not a class cluster or an abstract object. Subclassing is perfectly fine.

Comment: And just an FYI because Eiko brings it up, you can not change the buttonType programmatically - you can only do it in IB. This shouldn't be a problem for most developers.

Comment: UIButton is NOT a class cluster. Apple documentation clearly points out what is a class cluster (NSArray is a class cluster for example). I would rely on Apple documentation and not hearsay.

Comment: For those who haven't bothered, PLEASE SUBSCRIBE to cocoa-dev@lists.apple.com because there are a lot of knowledgeable people there. Despite many rumors (and that is what they are) UIButton **can** be subclassed. I'm not sure why **WRONG** information is bumped up and correct information is bumped down. If you believe it can not be subclassed, **provide proof**. I and many others have been subclassing UIButton for years.

Comment: [Matt Neuburg](http://www.apeth.net/matt/cv/computercareer.html) writes professionally for iOS (as I do). He has talked about subclassing UIButton [here](http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2010/Jun/msg00244.html) - no comments about how it is impossible. How about his book? "iOS 5" from O'Reilly - Page 730 [here](http://tinyurl.com/a6c9pps) talks about **subclassing UIButton**.

Comment: Please give a link to the Apple docs talking about subclassing UIButton. I can't find those.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do this, is to override a UIView. In the view you add a UIButton as Subview. This way you have a reusable class without the need to re-implement button behaviour.

You can style your button the way you want in the initWithFrame method of your UIView derived class. If you use this class as target for your button events, you can implement special behaviour easily, like showing the image.

For the two pieces of text, you create two labels and add them as subviews to the button.