# How to add properties/methods to UIButton

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I need to add two additional properties (NSString * and NSMutableArray *) along with three extra methods to UIButton. I also want to reference the new objects using a supertype if that is possible. I do not necessarily want to subclass (as I read that it is tricky and not recommended), but I am quite new to Objective-C and iOS development and don't know what else to do.

I tried to subclass UIButton with my subclass implementing a formal protocol in the following way:

```
@interface Button : UIButton <MyProtocol> ...
```

However, I found out this doesn't work like I thought it would, as buttonWithType: returns an object from a subclass. What else can I do to achieve the desired result?

-- EDIT:
Ok, my current code is like this:

```
@interface Button : UIButton <SteapeObject> {
    ActionQueue * actions;
    Meta meta;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) ActionQueue * actions;
@property (nonatomic) Meta meta;

- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame;
...
```

And the implementation:

```
- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        NSLog (@"finally");
    }

    return self;
}
```

An still doesn't work. It seems that when I invoke:

```
Button * button = [Button buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
NSLog (@"%@", [button description]);
```

I should get two 'finally' strings and two descriptions in the log. However, I only get the two description strings:

```
[Session started at 2011-02-24 09:47:14 +0100.]
2011-02-24 09:47:15.431 IphoneClient3[702:207] <UIRoundedRectButton: 0x5f47690; frame = (0 0; 0 0); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x5f47240>>
2011-02-24 09:47:15.461 IphoneClient3[702:207] <UIRoundedRectButton: 0x6a0f000; frame = (0 0; 0 0); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x6a344b0>>
```

And you can see that the type is still UIRoundedRectButton, but the buttons do not respond to my added methods. Actually, since my overriden initWithFrame doesn't get called, that is to be expected. Perhaps I should default to implementing a custom control...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that it is not possible to accomplish that task with the current implementation of the SDK.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the doc does not say subclassing of `UIButton` is not recommended.

I have done it multiple times to add custom properties — without problems.
The only thing to do is to create the button using:

```
[Button buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]; // won't work for other button types though
```

Comment: If I do that, what type is the button going to be? Is it going to be of the subclass I created, or some other private subclass? Also, is the newly created button going to respond to my added methods? And is it going to respond to the protocol messages that I've implemented?

Comment: I've run some tests. Looks like it works for `UIButtonTypeCustom` but no for `UIButtonTypeRoundedRect` or others. My bad, I was assuming it would behave the same. Edited the answer to precise that.

Comment: @Shade if you need to use button type other than UIButtonTypeCustom, I would suggest a category on UIButton as the other answers do.

Comment: But since I'll be adding extras to `UIButton`, will my `UIRoundRectButton` have/respond to the same extras?

Answer (score 2):

Use a [Category](http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/macsploitation/extending-classes-in-objectivec-with-categories-27447).

```
@interface UIButton (MyButtonCategory)
- (void) myMethod;

@end


@implementation UIButton (MyButtonCategory)
- (void) myMethod
{
   NSLog(@"Called myMethod!");
}

@end
```

---

[EDIT]

Alternatively, if I finally understand you, you can do this.

```
@interface MyButton : UIButton

- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)rect;

@end

@implementation MyButton

- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)rect
{
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:rect])){

    // Do your init in here

    }
    return self;

}
```

@end

Then calling

```
MyButton *btn = [MyButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
```

Should get you what you want.  `buttonWithType` should call `initWithFrame` on your subclass.

Comment: But since I'll be adding extras to `UIButton`, will my `UIRoundRectButton` have/respond to the same extras?

Comment: @Shade, no, if you are subclassing then you don't need a Protocol or Category.  Just add it like you would to a subclass of NSObject.  [UIButton](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html) can be subclassed.  Objects like [NSArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) however should not be subclassed, because they are clusters.

Comment: My point was if I use a category (and decide not to subclass) AND if I instantiate my button like this `UIButton * button = [UIBUtton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeRoundRect]`, then will my `button` respond to the added methods/ have the added properties?

Comment: @Shade, no.  I don't think you can extend buttonWithType like that.  Try my Edit above.  I recommend abandoning the idea of calling it with a type.  `UIButton *button = [MyButton button];` will be much, much easier.

Comment: @Stephen, thank you for taking the time to answer so thoroughly :) However, do objects of `UIButton` (and subclasses) respond to `initWithType`? Also, if this is an undocumented method that _does_ work, will it be bad for the acceptance of my app in the Apple AppStore? And also, my point was to be able to use the RoundRect button after all and not go through the trouble of initializing a custom button and styling it myself, because I want nothing special from these buttons - just some extra properties and a few methods that have to do only with my custom properties.

Comment: @Shade, more edits are up.  If that last bit is what works, then I'll remove the "misunderstandings"

Comment: @Stephen. I actually tried something similar to your last edit, but it didn't work. However, it was the end of a 10 hour working day and I was really tired, so I could've messed something up. I'll try it tomorrow and tell about the results here.

Comment: @Stephen. It doesn't work like that - I suppose that initWithFrame is not the default initializer for that method or.. ? See my edit above.

Comment: @Shade, [it appears `UIButton` is a class cluster?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679239/making-a-custom-button-using-a-uiview-or-overriding-uibutton) I'm sorry.  I don't think any of this will help.  Try it with `UIButtonTypeCustom` to see if it works.

Comment: @Stephen, I tried with all types and it returns either a UIButton or a UIRoundedRectButton, but never an object from my class. I dropped it and changed the logic to go around this problem (good thing that the Button was the first thing I was implementing :). Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Categories might help. Implement like this:

```
//In the UIButtonMyExtras.h file
@interface UIButton(MyExtras)
//extras
@end


//In the UIButtonMyExtras.m file
@implementation UIButton(MyExtras)
//extra implementation
@end
```

This adds these extras to every UIButton in your project.