# Any point in subclassing UIButton to create a custom looking button?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I want to create a set of buttons that would work and feel very much like the [Metro-style tiles that are available on Windows Phones](http://www.xda-developers.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/live-tiles.jpg?139d23). I would like to allow the user to tap them to access their underlying functionality (open a modal or something or that sort).

1. I'm concerned that subclassing UIButton will not get me there. I need square corners and dynamic content inside the tiles themselves. The posts I've found around SO seem to suggest that [subclassing a UIButton would not be a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3679398/511882) for several reasons and that I should instead use UIView. **That reply is from 2010**, and  I have no idea if in the 2+ years since then there have been considerable changes to how one would achieve that effect. Most users these days will have iOS 5.1+ if not 6.0 soon.
2. Let's say I do go the UIView route. Should I implement UIResponder's touch events or should I instead go the UITapGestureRecognizer route? What's the better practice in 2012?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest subclassing from `UIControl` instead of `UIButton`. I've seen how those windows tiles look and work in some videos including flipping animations when content changes etc., and it would be easier to package that functionality into a `Tile` class or something similar than having to carry a modified UIButton everywhere, and doing it for every such instance you need to create.

The reason I'm suggesting to not subclass from `UIButton` is because it provides support for 1 image and 1 label. You seem to have multiple images and labels on all tiles, so you'll have to start managing your own subviews. Instead of working around the 1 label and image you get in a `UIButton`, it's cleaner to start from scratch with a `UIControl` and create your tiles.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks for the response! How would you recommend I handle the touch events I mention in point 2?

Comment: UIControl is the parent class of UIButton and is already capable of handling touch events. You'd add a touch up handler to a UIControl object as you'd do it for the button by calling the selector `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:`

Comment: Do you believe there would be any benefit form using UITapGestureRecognizer in this specific situation?

Comment: I wouldn't complicate it any more than it needs to be. Gesture recognizers are great for gestures or if you need to handle gestures parallel to the responder chain but looking at your example, it appears that you're only interested in a simple tap, which UIControl offers out of the box.

Comment: Thanks, just what I wanted to know!

Answer (score 0):

if you just desire to have square metro style buttons that pretty much act like regular buttons (push them and something happens), then you can get all the functionality out of the standard UIButton class using a custom button without subclassing.

here is a quick example, in code, but this can be accomplished in IB as well.
say you have an image called: tile1.png

```
//set the image
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tile1.jpg"];

//create the button
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

//add the image
[button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];

//define the action
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTouched:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

If you need to modify the frame size you can via button.frame 
You can also modify a number of other button properties.

Did you know all that and were looking for something else or does that help?
be well

Comment: As well you could add several images depending on the State [button setImage:image forState:XXX], You have selected, highlighted, disable, etc.

Answer (score 0):

A use case would be to use a custom-looking button within Storyboard / Interface Builder. Having a subclass allows you to directly use this custom-looking button from Interface Builder.