# Create UIButton LIKE control with custom drawRect code

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, core-graphics, uicontrol

I would like to create a custom shape that acts like a `UIButton`. I need it to send `touchUpInside` to a target like a button however I want to use `drawRect` to change the button appearance when the buttons state changes.

I've read a lot of conflicting things on the net about not subclassing `UIButton` or `UIControl`.

1. So what it the acceptable way to do this?
2. Also if the answer is `UIControl` then how do you implement `touchUpInside` using the '`beginTracking`' methods?
3. Why can't we subclass `UIButton`. I've read things about it been a class cluster and not using `UIButtonTypeCustom` because it will not work but why is this?

I hope someone could shed some light on this or point me to some good reading.

Thank you.

Comment: see if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679239/making-a-custom-button-using-a-uiview-or-overriding-uibutton

Comment: After reading the discussion/argument the guys have i'm still a little confused. If its safe to subclass UIButton why would you have to use IB to change its type? Seems a little bit of a hack. What do you think?

Comment: Expect the reasons mentioned [here in Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIControl) I don't think subclassing UIButton is good idea. Consider subclassing UIView or using custom UIButton type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same sort of issue when I wanted to do a custom button. I also have read many posts that don't seem to hit on the right way to subclass `UIButton`. In your case, I would recommend subclassing `UIButton` and override the `setHighlighted:` method for adjusting the button on selection. I have a subclass of `UIButton` called `LDGradientButton` that can be found at [lightdesign/LDGradientButton](https://github.com/lightdesign/LDGradientButton). Feel free to take a look at the drawing code. In my case, I was using `CALayers`, but if I was doing it over, I'd probably use `CoreGraphics`.